# Using F# to Build a Highly Debuggable Business Rules Engine

Tags: f#, business-rules, quotations

### The Problem

I have code in F# representing a logical tree. It’s a Business Rules Engine with some fairly simple mathematical functions. I would like to be able to run the rules of the tree many times and see how many times each specific route through the tree is taken.

The requirements are that the base rules should not be changed too much from the simple match statements I’m using at the moment. Tagging the important functions with an attribute would be fine, but adding a call to a logging function at every node is not. I want to be able to run the code in two modes, a highly performant standard mode which just gives answers, and then an “exploratory mode” which gives more detail behind each call. While I don’t mind complicated code to dynamically load and profile the rules, the rules code itself must look simple. Ideally I’d like to not rely on 3rd party libraries - powerpack is ok. The solution must also target the .NET 4.0 runtime.

### Potential Solutions

1. Add a logging call to every function with the function name and arguments. I don’t like this because even if I could disable it in some kind of release mode, it still clutters the rules and means all new code has to be written in an unnatural way.
2. Each function return its result, and then a list which contains the names of the methods so far called. I don’t like this because it would look unnatural, and would carry a performance hit. I’m sure I could use a computational expression to do a lot of the plumbing, but that violates the requirement to keep the rules simple.
3. Parse the rules tree using quotations, and then build a new expression which is the old expression with a call to a logging function injected into the site of each tagged function. This is the best thing I’ve got so far, but I’m worried about compiling the resulting quotation so I can run it. I understand (please correct me if I’m wrong) that not all quotations can be compiled. I’d rather not have an unstable process that limits the rules code to a subset of the F# language. If the rules compile, I would like my solution to be able to deal with them.

I know this is a difficult problem with a fairly strict set of requirements, but if anyone has any inspiration for a solution, I would be very grateful.

*Edit*: Just to give an example of the sort of rules I might be using, if I owned a widget factory producing products A and B the simple following code might be used. I don't want to lose the readability and simplicity of the formulas by adorning this layer with helper functions and hooks.

```
type ProductType = | ProductA | ProductB

let costOfA quantity =
    100.0 * quantity

let costOfB quantity =
    if quantity < 100.0 then
        20.0 * quantity
    else
        15.0 * quantity

let calculateCostOfProduct productType quantity =
    match productType with
    | ProductA -> costOfA quantity
    | ProductB -> costOfB quantity
```

Comment: I appreciate it's a bit of a disconnect, but while the rules need to look simple, I'd like them to represent the full F# language. The reason is that I will only be writing one half of this, and I don't want to have to explain to people writing the rules what features they can and can't use. Would your solution involve writing an implementation for every method found in the rules, or evaluating a quotation built using ``ReflectedDefinition``?

Comment: What about modifying the CIL after the fact, using something like PostSharp (http://www.postsharp.net/aspects)?  Not very F# like, but might suit your needs?